# Title's will not show translated version (multilingual site) in View list

Tags: 7, views, commerce, i18n-l10n

I am working on a multilingual drupal website (webshop with commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.37, drupal 7.43).

My articles are perfectly translated, even the titles. So when I go to the page of the article and change the language it shows the translated content including title.

I then made a new view. With that view i created a page to have all the titles of the articles in a list. The thing is though that those titles will not translate when i change the site language while it does perfectly change on the article itself!

Any help? Is it because I do not have internationalization views? I don't get why it is translating on the article itself but not on the overview page.

Comment: Are you displaying fields with the view or rendered content? Rendered content should display translated always, maybe with fields you have to choose a translated field, if there's such thing

Comment: I am displaying fields with the view, not rendered content.

Comment: not sure if it matters though. The content gets translated (body) elswhere and that is also displayed as a field and not rendered content. Funnily enough, there as well the title will not be translated so it is purely the title that is creating issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it myself.

when using fields, instead of adding content:title as a field, use entity translation:title. This will show the same field as your title but the translated version.